# how to install curl 7.15.5 libcurl 7.15.5, OpenSSL 0.9.8b, zlib 1.2.3, libidn 0.6.5 in Kali Linux?

Tags: kali-linux

I just want to install those thing in my kali linux. But I don't know the command. Can you tell me what the command for install those? This is just order from my teacher,but I want to install all the lastest version of theirs. Can you help me too?

Comment: hey, anyone here to help me?

Comment: Don't. Use a real distribution that has actual package management. Debian, Arch, Ubuntu, CentOS.